# How to unversion a file just for you and not the other developers

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control

One of the other developers added pre-build events to our Silverlight and server projects in Visual Studio. It didn't affect any other developers, just me. For some reason I cannot build and run our application without removing the pre-build events.

It looks like modifying the pre-build events only changes the .csproj file, which is under version control (svn). Is there anyway for me to ignore this file when doing an svn commit or a better solution?

I've looked into svn delete --keep-local and editing svn:ignore but it seems like that would essentially unversion it for the other developers as well.

Comment: You should probably spend more time figuring out why the pre-build events fail *only for you*, rather than trying to come up with a very hacky workaround.

Comment: +1 for @KirkWoll's comment - you should definitely fix it instead of hacking your build process.

Comment: We have been trying that and it has gotten to the point where it is hindering development too much and we need a hack and until we can find a long term solution.

Comment: How many developers are there?  If it is just you and one other developer then he has local files that are breaking your build.

Answer (score 0):

In *Tortoise SVN* client there is an 'ignore-on-commit' changelist - *Tortoise* by default won't commit files on that changelist (here's [more info on changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.changelists.html)). So, one option is to use Tortoise SVN and add files you want to ignore on commit to the changelist.

Another option is to write your own custom commit script that will run `svn status`, filter out files in 'ignore-on-commit' changelist, and commit the rest. Here's the pseudo-code:

```
svn status --changelist "ignore-on-commit" > ignored.tmp
for every line in ignored.tmp:
   file = parse_file_name from line
   cp file file.bak
   svn revert file
svn ci [other options passed to the script]
for every line in ignored.tmp:
   file = parse_file_name from line
   mv file.bak file
rm ignored.tmp
```

Unfortunately, the standard command-line SVN client still lacks a very useful feature to specify that you want to run your command on everything **but** the changelist.